# How can I circumvent a raised exception (even when using find_by_id)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As the title suggests - an exception was being raised in production on Heroku, even when I use find_by_id. I'm not sure what the cause is, but I have used a `begin/ensure` to circumvent the issue, but I am still running into an issue.

here was my initial solution:

```
    def select_location
        begin
            region = Region.find_by_id(params[:Digits])
        ensure
            Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|

                # if user pressed "9" (redirect)
                if (params[:Digits] == '0')

                    @response = r.Redirect call_hq_path, method: 'GET'

                # if region does not exist
                elsif !region.id
                    @response = r.Play Clip.where(name: "invalid").first.url
                    @response = r.Redirect index_path, method: 'GET'
                else
                    @response = r.Gather action: location_description_path(region), numDigits: '1' do |g|
                        region.locations.order(:number).each do |location|
                            g.Play location.listing_clip.url
                            g.Play number_url(location.number)
                        end
                        g.Play Clip.where(name: "9toreturn").first.url
                    end
                end
            end
        end

        render :xml => @response
    end
```

The problem here lies at `elsif !region.id`  - am still running into this error:

```
2013-10-18T01:29:14.524289+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
```

So, my two questions:

- is `begin/ensure` the best way to circumvent the issue?
- if yes, how do I fix the `elsif` problem?

**update**

After removing `.id` from the `elsif` - I get this error:

```
2013-10-18T02:06:57.055617+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass):
```

How is the `elsif` not firing?

Comment: we need full errors - you're referencing multiple `url`s, and any one of them could be on a nil object.

Comment: Feel free to ask a follow up question if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

`elsif !region.id` does not check if region exists, it checks if `id` property of the `region` object returns `nil`. If `region` doesn't exist (and hence is `nil`), you're effectively calling `nil.id`, which is what is raising the exception.

If you just want to check if `region` is `nil`, `elsif !region` should suffice.

(From what you have here, it also doesn't really look like there's any need for the `begin`/`ensure` block either.)

Comment: just posted an update. any ideas? also - i don't need the ensure in my local environment, but heroku throws an exception for the `find_by_id`

Comment: `find_by_id` does not throw an exception.